# Python- Twitter crawler

Tags: python, twitter

I would like to inquire if there is any method that allow my crawler to go all the way down to the bottom of the page, and wait for the page to load(so that the html of the loaded post will be added). As twitter's html code only show a few post and u have to manually scroll down for the html to be refreshed after the bottom post are loaded. The `<html></html>` tag will only show the currently existing post, and my crawler will stop.

```
def spider(targetname, DOMAIN, g_data):
    for item in g_data:
        try:
            name = item.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "})[0].text
            username = item.find_all("span", {"class": "username u-dir"})[0].text
            post = item.find_all("p", {"class": "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})[0].text
            replies = item.find_all("span", {"class": "u-hiddenVisually"})[3].text
            retweets = item.find_all("span", {"class": "u-hiddenVisually"})[4].text
            likes = item.find_all("span", {"class": "u-hiddenVisually"})[5].text
            retweetby = item.find_all("a", {"href": "/"+targetname})[0].text
            datas = item.find_all('a', {'class':'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
            for data in datas:
                link = DOMAIN + data['href']
                date = data['title']
            append_to_file(crawledfile, name, username, post, link, replies, retweets, likes, retweetby, date)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: how is your crawler written?

Comment: i have updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 0):

That would require the crawler to execute javascript while crawling, which I believe most crawlers won't. You may find you can do whatever you're trying to do using [Twitter's official REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) instead.

Also using APIs where possible will usually be more reliable than scraping web pages. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what swalladge mentioned, there are plenty of Twitter packages for Python that mean you don't even need to really read Twitter's API to do what you are trying to do! Just search for `Twitter Python` to get numerous suggestions.

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks! Will check on it in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

A crawler can't execute JavaScript functions and get new output, so all you see is what you get. If a website that uses AJAX wants to be crawlable it needs to provide HTML snapshots of how it would look like for a normal user.

In your case that would be outputting all the tweets but who knows how much data that is. However Twitter likes to be crawled as it makes them easily viewable in search engines, so there's an API you can use.

Comment: Okay, will take a look at the API.